# Parsing PDF pages as javascript Images

Tags: javascript, image, bash, pdf

As per title, is there any way I can parse pages from an unprotected PDF file as javascript Image() objects?

It would also be ok to convert them before running the javascript, but I would like this to be done automatically and without the assistance of any library which requires installation.

Someone over the internet has posted this Bash script. Unfortunately, I don't know Bash but running it was very simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
PDF='doc.pdf'
NUMPAGES=`identify -format %n "$PDF"`

for (( IDX=0; IDX<$NUMPAGES; IDX++ ))
do
  PAGE=$(($IDX+1))
  convert -resize 1200x900 "$PDF[$IDX]" `echo "$PDF" | sed "s/\.pdf$/-page$PAGE.jpg/"`
done

echo "Done"
```

But I got these errors:

```
line 3: identify: command not found
line 5: ((: IDX<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
```

Pre-converting the PDF using a Bash script would be a good solution. Can someone fix the script above or either provide an alternative solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why not using python and 1 of the gozillion libraries that you can use for free ?

Comment: @Ken, can you tell more about this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) will let you render the PDF to a canvas. Then you can do something like:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = pdfCanvas.toDataURL();
```

I've been very impressed with PDF.js. I love letting the client's browser do as much of the work for me as possible.

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/1/edit

Comment: Here is a gist with working code:
https://gist.github.com/ichord/9808444

Comment: @MPV Not working anymore. Would you have another link?

Comment: @Basj it did load but slowly. But it works. If errors, let me know what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first issue is a missing executable: `identify`. This is part of ImageMagick:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Make sure you also have it in your path.

Comment: so it uses imagemagick! Very bad, I didn't wanted to use it but it looks like it is the only solution. Thx!

Comment: @Saturnix `convert` is also part of the imagemagick libraries, this script is entirely based on imagemagick .

Comment: [Here is a recent example that works great](https://github.com/meirlamdan/merge-pdf/blob/master/src/pdfToImg.js)