# creating Page turner effect for PDF files with angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to create page turner effect for PDF files with angular? Jquery solutions are also fine. I have seen turn.js which uses html. Can any one help out to find a way for PDF files?

Comment: Where is this turn.js file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the pages within a PDF having a page curl effect then it is not something you can do with js, html or anything else outside the PDF itself without converting the PDF to something else (ie flash, jpg images, etc).

Last time I checked the only way to achieve this within a PDF was by using Acrobat Pro or InDesign and using 'Page Transitions'.
Please note that out of the available page transitions 'Page Turn' (the curl effect you want) will cause the document to be converted to a flash file and then embedded in the PDF.

I'm sorry if this is not what you want to hear.  Rather than creating fancy page curl/turn effects it is probably better to concentrate on producing a well designed, easy to navigate document with great content.  This will provide much better value.

Comment: Thanks Tims For your comments.... Can this be accomplished with PDF.js + turn.js combination? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I believe it's possible. I know the PDF.js codebase well and since it's basically a canvas, you can definitely do it.

Comment: @Hengjie It would be really helpful if you could provide an example.

Comment: I tried this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/12921304/2633915. But the image that is getting generated is blank. It does not have my contents