# Convert PDF to Image [.JPG] in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a UI screen in React JS that contains input [type='file'], where i select PDF files, and after selecting the PDF file, i have to convert PDF to Image file [.JPG format] in frontend and i want to upload the converted Image file and selected PDF file to s3 bucket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing PDF pages as javascript Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921052/parsing-pdf-pages-as-javascript-images)