# pdf to image ionic_app capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

it is my first post hier. I've been looking for a solution to my problem for a long time but haven't found the right one yet.
I want to convert pdf to image on my ionic app with capacitor. is that possible? if yes how? thx

i hope someone has the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using [`pdf.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) for example. Here you can find more information in another SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921304/6731412

Comment: thx @RGe for your answer. I‘ll try this