# convert PDF to Image angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting blob PDF from API. the PDF contains some pages, and I want to convert every page to image. the result I'm hoping is I get the list of image. And then I want to display that image in HTML.

i already tried many ways, the latest code i try is

```
let thisIsMyPDF = new Blob([data.body], {type: 'application/pdf'});
console.log(blob);
```

and

```
const imagePath = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,'
                                        + data.body);

let objectURL = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data.body;
this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
```

display image

```
<img id="image1" class="bi x0 y0 w1 h1" alt=""
                         [src]="image"/>
```

its easy to find image to PDF library, or HTML to PDF library. But its hard to find PDF to image library.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921052/parsing-pdf-pages-as-javascript-images

Comment: And what is the purpose of converting it to an image? If you just want to display it, there is probably a more straightforward solution

Comment: display the pdf in a canvas using pdfjs, then you can save the canvas as an image

Comment: @A_A for some purpose. if i just want to display it. i can use ng-pdf-viewer or other library. but i display it as image for spesific purpose

Comment: @Zerotwelve no, thats not my purpose. my purpose is display it as image. not pdf.  "display PDF as Image".

Comment: with a canvas you can generate an image and show it using a `<img>` tag, but that's overkill. It's better to use <canvas> directly.
Another option is to generate some thumbnails server-side and then load the images.
I think you don't have many other options

Comment: @RisliAzis Then please take a look at the question I've linked above. This shows how you can use pdfjs to display it as an image